# how to convert string to mysql date format using vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i want to insert a string as date format in mysql table using vb.net.my code is given below.but i always get an error .the string is stored in an array.

```
mycode
------

Dim sdfsa As String = Convert.ToDateTime(newarray(i + 17)).ToShortDateString().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
Dim newdate As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(sdfsa, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
datarw("date_of_birth") = newdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the Users inputting this information directly?

if they are why don't you input have them input the value in a masked text box?

This [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/49e922e2-2d69-4c66-acb5-3764e02857fc/) Could Help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_date =Format(Now,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim year, month, day As Integer
    Dim date_value As Date
    Dim date_final_to_mySQL As String


    date_value = DateTimePicker1.Value

    year = date_value.Year
    month = date_value.Month
    day = date_value.Day

    date_final_to_mySQL = year & "-" & month & "-" & day

    MessageBox.Show(date_final_to_mySQL)

End Sub
```

Only need create a button1 and datetimepicker1

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRaPJ.png)